# Editing pic TIKZ block

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic

I'm drawing the following diagram:

[image]

And I'd like to pass "PWM Inverter" as a parameter when creating the block, which I couldn't do...
Also, I'd like to increase the size of the text inside the block. How do I do it?

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,patterns,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/inverter/.style 2 args={code={%
\path (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/width}/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2)
 node[above right] (bl) {#2}
 rectangle
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/width}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2)
 node[below left] (tr) {#1};
 \node[pic actions,inner sep=0pt,fit=(bl)(tr),path picture={\path[pic actions]
 (path picture bounding box.north west)
 -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}] 
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/name}){};
 \node at (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2) [rectangle, above]{PWM Inverter};
}},inverter/.cd,height/.initial=2cm,width/.initial=2cm,name/.initial=}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path pic[draw,thick,rounded corners,text centered,inverter/name=inv] {inverter={$\sim$}{$\sim$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason this code looks very familiar to me so it was easy to modify and to add a key for the title. The default (or, more precisely, initial) value is `PWM Inverter` but you can change it, as illustrated in the MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/inverter/.style 2 args={code={%
\path (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/width}/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2)
 node[above right,scale=2] (bl) {#2}
 rectangle
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/width}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2)
 node[below left,scale=2] (tr) {#1};
 \node[pic actions,inner sep=0pt,fit=(bl)(tr),path picture={\path[pic actions]
 (path picture bounding box.north west)
 -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}] 
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/name}){};
 \node at (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/height}/2) 
 [rectangle, above]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inverter/title}};
}},inverter/.cd,height/.initial=2cm,width/.initial=2cm,name/.initial=,%
title/.initial=PWM Inverter}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path pic[draw,thick,rounded corners,text centered,inverter/name=inv] {inverter={$\sim$}{$\sim$}}
(5,0) pic[draw,thick,rounded corners,text centered,inverter/.cd,name=inv2,title=some title]
{inverter={$\sim$}{$\sim$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How could we  increase the text size inside the block (I mean turning "~" bigger)?

Comment: @ClecioJung Add `scale=2` or something like that to the options of the node.